# How to update with mongoose on Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

Please i need help. i am trying to update my post on Node and mongoose but it's not working, i have followed the docs on mongoose site and examples on stackoverflow but it still doesn't work. when i update it gives me status code of 302 and when i console.log the result of the update it gives me this number that i don't really understand `{ n: 1, nModified: 0, ok: 1 }`

my `routes/posts.js`

```
router.post('/edit/:id', (req, res) => {
  let post = {};
  post.title = req.body.title;
  post.description = req.body.description;
  post.from = req.body.from;
  let query = {_id: req.params.id}
  Post.updateOne(query, post , {new:true},  (err, post) => {
    console.log(post)
    if(err){
      console.log(err)
      res.redirect("back");
    }else {
      res.redirect("/posts");
    }
 });
});
```

my `posts/edit.ejs`

```
 <form action="/posts/edit/<%=post._id %>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <%- include('_form_fields') %>
    <a href="/posts">Cacel</a>
    <button type="submit">Update</button>
</form>
```

my `app.js`

```
var postRouter = require('./routes/posts');
app.use('/posts', postRouter);
```

my schema

```
 const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
title: {
     type: String,
     required: true
},
description: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
from: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
createdAt: { 
    type: Date, 
    required: true, 
    default: Date.now
},
postImage: {
    type: String,
    require: true
},
comments: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }]
```

})

and this is the result on console

```
{ n: 1, nModified: 0, ok: 1 }
```

i really don't know what i am doing wrong here, i followed the examples i saw online and docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@chuckwuma 
yeah the syntax for updateOne is correct. but make sure the req.body contained the specified keys and secondly all the key that you try to update are exist in mongoose schema and with same name as you mentioned with post.__ 
and remove the option object {new: true} form it doesn't accepted by update one parameter if you want to take newly updated result you can go for .
findOneAndUpdate() for that.

Comment: i am updating everything that is in the schema except date which creates itself and image which doesn't need to be included before it creates. i have updated my post with my schema for you to see

Comment: okay then please use line 
Post.updateOne(query, {$set: post} ,  (err, post) => {
instead of 
Post.updateOne(query, post , {new:true},  (err, post) => {
and please console req.body and make sure it contained specified keys.

Comment: @Padeep, your initial question regarding making sure that my keys and schema are being passed made me thinking and i decided to include image attribute on my update, and it updated correctly. Thank you so much for pointing me towards the right direction.  and i am sorry for doing what you asked me to do immediately. everything works fine now and my post is updating.